# Using main JDBC connection pool in utility classes

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a use case say,

A java application **App1** connects to **xxx.xxx.xxx.101:3306/sampledb1** mysql database, and a connection pool (with poolname **Pool1**) is configured in this application.

Now this application has 2 utlity jars which needs access to same **xxx.xxx.xxx.101:3306/sampledb1** mysql database.

I don't want to create 3 connection pools in utility jars and application.

I want to reuse the connection pool created in **App1** for utility as well.

Comment: If you wrap around the connection pool and expose it in a separate that gets used by your application and the other two utility jars, do you face a problem? The problem statement isn't clear on what is the real challenge.

Comment: That is what dependency injection is for.

Comment: @Mark - In its simplest form would that just be the utility methods accepting a `java.sql.Connection` parameter for the connection they should be using (regardless of whether or not it came from a connection pool)?

Comment: @GordThompson Possibly, or a data source.